# How to join a slice of strings into a single string?

Tags: go, slice

```
package main

import (
"fmt"
"strings"
)

func main() {
reg := [...]string {"a","b","c"}
fmt.Println(strings.Join(reg,","))
}
```

gives me an error of:

> prog.go:10: cannot use reg (type [3]string) as type []string in argument to strings.Join

Is there a more direct/better way than looping and adding to a var?

Comment: Why not just use `reg := []string {"a","b","c"}`?

Answer (score 269, accepted):

The title of your question is:

> How to join a slice of strings into a single string?

but in fact, `reg` is *not* a slice, but a length-three array. `[...]string` is just syntactic sugar for (in this case) `[3]string`.

To get an actual slice, you should write:

```
reg := []string {"a","b","c"}
```

(Try it out: https://play.golang.org/p/vqU5VtDilJ.)

Incidentally, if you ever really do need to join an array of strings into a single string, you can get a slice from the array by adding `[:]`, like so:

```
fmt.Println(strings.Join(reg[:], ","))
```

(Try it out: https://play.golang.org/p/zy8KyC8OTuJ.)

Comment: Pls, provide the working code in the answer itself, playground is a plus but not enough for acceptable answer ;-). TY!

Comment: @shadyyx: I agree that the playground link is strictly supplemental; but I'm not sure what you think is missing from the answer proper. The OP's sole error was on line 10, and I provided the corrected version of that line, together with explanation. (Are you suggesting that I should have copied his/her entire example program into the answer? If so, then -- I disagree.)

Comment: "trying to join a slice into a string" Your solution only works for **slices of strings** instead of the general slice type.

Answer (score 129):

Use a slice, not an arrray. Just create it using

```
reg := []string {"a","b","c"}
```

An alternative would have been to convert your array to a slice when joining :

```
fmt.Println(strings.Join(reg[:],","))
```

Read [the Go blog about the differences between slices and arrays](http://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals).

Answer (score 44):

### This is still relevant in 2018.

To String

```
import strings
stringFiles := strings.Join(fileSlice[:], ",")
```

Back to Slice again

```
import strings
fileSlice := strings.Split(stringFiles, ",")
```

Comment: import "strings"